# How to move file(s)/dir to recycle bin in Java instead of deleting it permanently

Tags: java, swing, file, java-8, java-7

I am trying to create example of GUI that's delete files and/or directories When user clicks on Button, but I see that files deleted permanently, How to make it moves to recycle bin instead of this

```
  if (File_path.getText().isEmpty()) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please select a file or directory", "Info", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    } else {
        File FileName = new File(File_path.getText());
        boolean FileDeleted = FileName.delete();
        if (FileDeleted == true) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File Deleted Successfully", "Info", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File Not Found", "Info", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Eugene I see this answer since 8 years and it's may be confused due to long lines (about 25) to delete one file!

Comment: @DrMido check the edit please :)

Comment: Took as long as [until Java 9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#moveToTrash-java.io.File-)…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, it is a bug fired but neglected because developers believe it `won't be cross-platform-compatible` if move to recycle bin functionality added. You can read about it [*here*](http://www.ryanlowe.ca/blog/archives/000574_java_delete_to_recycle_bin.php)

using **C++** : But you can do with `External APIs`. With the help of `JNI` to invoke the Windows `SHFileOperation` API, setting the `FO_DELETE` flag in the `SHFILEOPSTRUCT` structure.

Here's the [Reference](http://www.jroller.com/ethdsy/entry/send_to_recycle_bin)

using **JAVA** :Use [`com.sun.jna.platform.win32.W32FileUtils`], which has `moveToTrash` and `hasTrash` methods defined.

Another ways is to use `com.sun.jna.platform.FileUtils;`

Sample code :

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import com.sun.jna.platform.FileUtils;

public class MoveToTrash {

  public static void main(String[] args){
    FileUtils fileUtils = FileUtils.getInstance();
    if (fileUtils.hasTrash()) {
        try {
            fileUtils.moveToTrash( new File[] {new File("c:/folder/abcd.txt") });                
        }
        catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("No Trash available");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: this reference explains how to do that on C++ not in Java

Comment: @DrMido Added Java part :) . Your question isn't duplicate still marked duplicate :/. If this satisfies as solution let me know :)

Comment: minigeek  I didn't vote negative for your comment, anyway can you edit your comment here "You can read about it " I cannot find the link for this bug